# Having spring context variable pointing to actual external contexts in webapp

Tags: java, spring, environment-variables, apache-camel

I am currently modifying our Apache Camel-based app to Tomcat. Because of business needs, we would have to host multiple instances of app on single machine, each with it's own set of config. Previously config files were bundled with app (and thus easily accessible from classpath), but now they will be separated in some absolute path (like path/instance1, path/instance2 etc). What I want to achieve with Spring:

- export instance conf path as variable in initial spring context file, so I can reference to it via ${instance_conf_path} (currently I have it in property file, read through PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer)
- have real spring contexts (they are logically separated) imported using  in the initial context mentioned
- since this path is also used in few parts of Apache Camel routing, I need to use this variable also there (this should work according to Camel's manual)

Camel 2.10.2 is has Spring 3.0.7 in transitive dependencies, but after reading [this article](http://blog.springsource.com/2011/02/15/spring-3-1-m1-unified-property-management/) I put manually Spring 3.1.2 into maven. But it was still complaining it doesn't know the variable. Any suggestions? Or do you know a better way in Spring to store all config externally and setting just path to this config in app bundle?
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider using an environment variable? You could refer to it from web.xml:

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>
    classpath*:spring/sharedContext.xml,
    file:/${APP_HOME}/spring/specificContext.xml
  </param-value>
</context-param>
```

If anything particular is needed for Camel, you could include instance specific configuration under appropriate APP_HOME.